# prove this inequality with log and positive value "x"

Tags: calculus, inequality

How do I prove that for every positive $x$ ,

$1-x \le -\log{x}$

Can I use convexity somehow?

Comment: My bad. Thanks for the edit!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Define

$$f(x)=\log x -x+1\implies f'(x)=\frac1x-1=0\iff x=1$$

But also

$$f''(x)=-\frac1{x^2}\implies f''(1)<0$$

so at $\;x=1\;$ we have a maximum, and then

$$\forall\;x>0\;,\;\;\;f(x)=\log x-x+1\le f(1)=0$$

and we're done.

Comment: The last step is what I was stuck at expressing.  Thanks a ton!

Answer (score 3):

> Can I use convexity somehow?

Using the convexity of $f(x)=-\log(x)$: 
$$
-\log(x)=f(x)\geq f(1)+f'(1)(x-1)=0+\left(-\frac{1}{1}\right)(x-1)=1-x.
$$

Answer (score 0):

defining $f(x)=-ln(x)-1+x$ we obtain by differentiating with respect to $x$
$f'(x)=1-\frac{1}{x}$ and
$f''(x)=\frac{1}{x^2}$
you will get one extrempoint for $x=1$ and this is a minimum.We have $f(1)=0$ further
$\lim_{x \to 0+}f(x)=+\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to \infty}f(x)=+\infty$.
Thus we have $f(x)\geq 0$ for all real $x$ with $x>0$.
Sonnhard.